# Can't get entry from textbook into a txt file

Tags: python, tkinter, file-handling, tkinter-entry

I'm a new Python programmer, and I was trying to make a simple Login and Register program using tkinter. I have my tkinter import at the top, and I think I have the necessary code in order to get the entry from the text boxes (usernameEntry and passwordEntry), then open a txt file, and write to it. However, it opens a new txt file (whatever I name it), but it doesn't write into it.

Here's a portion of my code:

```
usernameEntry = Entry(frameUsername, width=15).pack(pady=20)
usernameEntry = StringVar()

passwordEntry = Entry(framePassword, width=15).pack(pady=5)
passwordEntry = StringVar()

def registerUser():
       username = usernameEntry.get()
       password = passwordEntry.get()

       f = open('User and Passes', 'w+')
       f.write(username)
       f.write(password)
       f.close()

buttonRegister = Button(regWindow, text='Confirm Registration', fg='black', width=20,
                            height=2, font=('times new roman', 12), command=registerUser).pack(pady=20)
```

I've tried append as well for the file mode, but the same thing still happens. Would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the point of the first line `usernameEntry = Entry(...)` when you immediately throw it away on the second line and re-declare `usernameEntry = StringVar()`?  And the same issue on the third and fourth lines.

Comment: If i don't declare it as StringVar after, I get this error message:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/afrideehaque/PycharmProjects/RockPaperScissors/Register and Login System.py", line 39, in registerUser
    username = usernameEntry.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Declaring `usernameEntry = StringVar()` means it's an empty variable, so when you try to write the contents into the file, there's nothing to write, which is the exact problem you have.  Presumably there was some point to the first line being there at all?

Comment: The first line was to have an entry box on the window, and then the second line was to declare that whatever was being put in the box was a string. Then in the function, I was trying to "get" the string that was put in the textbox, and then write it into the txt file. At least that was my thought process. But I see what you're saying. I tried putting the "StringVar" line above "Entry", but I'm having the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the text files are empty is as both the `StringVar` **(usernameEntry, passwordEntry)** variables are empty even when if the `Entry` widgets are not empty beasuse they're not linked. There are couple of problems with your code.

1. Don't use any geometry manager *(pack, place, grid)* in the same line you if you are initiating a variable, you either do

   ```
   Entry(frameUsername, width=15).pack(pady=20)
   ```

   or

   ```
   usernameEntry = Entry(frameUsername, width=15)
   usernameEntry.pack(pady=20)`
   ```

   Please don't do this `usernameEntry = Entry(frameUsername, width=15).pack(pady=20)` as it'll always return a `None` value.
2. You can get whatever the value is in an `Entry` widget just from the `Entry` widget's object like so `usernameEntry.get()`. (*As long as you follow the first step)* So just by doing as below everything should work fine.

   ```
   usernameEntry = Entry(frameUsername, width=15)
   usernameEntry.pack(pady=20)

   passwordEntry = Entry(framePassword, width=15)
   passwordEntry.pack(pady=5)
   ```
3. When using `StringVar` or any other Tkinter variable you have to tell the  widget that you are using `StringVar` like so

   ```
   usernameEntry = StringVar()
   Entry(frameUsername, width=15, textvariable=usernameEntry).pack(pady=20)
   ```

   Using `StringVar` is not very useful when you can get the value straight from the `Entry` widget, `StringVar` is useful when you want to change the same value at multiple places or use `trace` method.